# How to make user-defined types work on ranges algorithms with operator overloading in c++20?

Tags: c++, c++20, std-ranges

In general, if I define class:

```
class A {
    public:
        A(int x) {
            data = x;
        }
        // Used for min_element()
        bool operator<(const A& a) const {
            return data < a.data;
        }
    private:
        int data;
    
};
```

The following works correctly.

```
int main(void) {
  std::vector<A> x {A(1), A(5), A(3)};
  auto min = std::min_element(std::begin(x), std::end(x));
  return 0;
}
```

However, operator overloading (`<` here) is not applied when the vector is used in `std::ranges::min_element`. Thus, the following does not work.

```
int main(void) {
      std::vector<A> x {A(1), A(5), A(3)};
      auto min = std::ranges::min_element(x);
      return 0;
}
```

According to the interface of `std::ranges::min_element` ([reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/ranges/min_element)), it seems that the operator overloaded is not used.

Is it possible to make `std::ranges::min_element` used same as `std::min_element` with operator overloading (might be something different)?

Comment: Ranges want a full set of relational operators, not only `<`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Works correctly, if I define all relational operators. Why do the users  have to define all relational operators for ranges? Are there any specific reasons?

Comment: Probably to force users to write better classes. I don't think `ranges::min_element` can call anything other than `<`.